# How to capture failed login in nerodia (watir)?

Tags: selenium, watir

I am trying to test an application using Nerodia, and I am having a hard time to figure out - how to log/capture a failed login attempt.

A toaster pops up for both success and failure. Currently the program captures screenshot for every attempt - both successful and failure. But I have to open the captured image to find if it was successful or not.

Logging in with wrong credentials is not an exception which I can catch using try/catch. Is there a way I can log the failure the same way as success ?

if I inspect Toaster’s HTML code, it disappears as soon as the Toaster disappears.

```
def login(browser):

    username = browser.text_field(name='username')
    username.value = user_name
    password = browser.text_field(name='password')
    password.value = pass_key

    browser.button(name='submit').click()
    browser.screenshot.save('screenshot.png')

    logger.info('login successful')
```

Comment: Interesting.  This looks like the first `nerodia` question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

On logging in , I check for an element on next page. If it exists , I log successful,  else fail

```
e = browser.ital(class_name='').exists
if e == True:
    logger.info('successful')
else :
    logger.info('failed')
```